# materialized view update time is not correct

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I don't know how the materialized view is updated. I created materialized view, and update it every minute.

```
create materialized view vmat 
refresh force on demand
start with to_date('07-08-2017 10:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
next sysdate+(1/(24*60)) 
as
 select * from mat where id>3;`
```

But it refreshed at the 2017/8/7 16:21:07 in the `user_mview_refresh_times`. It should be updated at 2017/8/7 16:21:00. So I am very confused.

Comment: so you are saying its updated 7 seconds AFTER you intended it to??

Comment: I think it is impossible to updated 7 seconds .Just 10 rows in the table.I start at 07-08-2017 10:00:00 and update the table every minute.So It should be updated at the beginning of every minute.I just do a test,and apply It to my work.

Comment: I do a little change,and let the materialized-views update every hour.I find it very strange.When I create the materialized view at '07-08-2017 10:15:24',the next update time is '07-08-2017 11:15:24'.It seems the 'start with' clause not works.No matter what 'start with' clause is.

Comment: The oracel database version is 11gR2.I think It should be updated at  '07-08-2017 11:00:00',rather than '07-08-2017 11:15:24'.

Answer (score 0):

The `next` parameter specifies the refresh time as a date time, which the database turns into an interval. I think the problem is you are defining `start`and `next` differently. In particular you are using a raw `sysdate`, which includes a time element to the exact second. That's why you got those odd values for LAST_REFRESH.

Try this formulation instead (using your original times):

```
...
, Start => trunc(sysdate)+(10/24)
, Next => trunc(sysdate)+(1/1440)
```

So, the initial start time will be 10:00:00 and the first refresh will be 10:01:00.

Comment: But the code you showed is not correct. When I create the materialized view,the view be updated for the first time.Then DBMS calculates the next date the view be updated.Yes I got. Thank you very much.I think         Next =>trunc(sysdate,'mi')+1/1440